# Facebook Authenticated Referrals &code

Tags: facebook, api, authentication, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I'm using Naitik Shah PHP library for Facebook. I've recently started playing with Authenticated Referrals, but I'm really, really confused. I'm not entirely sure how to work with both systems in tandem and find the Facebook documentation confusing at best.

In my Facebook settings I'm using Auth Token Parameter: Querystring which returns a code.

*Query String: if your app is using server-side authentication. If your app is a canvas app, we will not use this setting and will use the "signed_request" as the response type automatically.*

The app is NOT a canvas app, so it's sending code.

*Return an access token or code*

As far as I can tell this is the only place in the entire API where code is sent. I'm not entire sure that that "code" is or what to do with it once I have it. I'm confused about the entire oauth thing doesn't help at all. **Being a programmer and bing a little thick on this matter, is there ANYONE out there with just a snippet of PHP code that exemplifies what to do with this request code to tease out the required information for authentication?**

Thank you!

---

Working with the new PHP library for Facebook will automatically work with the code variable from Authentication Referrals.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is "What is a signed request?"...

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for the help. 

I'm not sure &code is a signed request, is it? Noting the lack of concatenation around a (.). Here's an example of the &code request varaible:

AQD2pgCelZknEzi7ORv6ZTPxlP4jGkvMY-rNlNpstbNA11ZWcFHf7K-6UvU0yZywwtxAq-4Fvb0hLSRXr0BfifG-VcuzexSNmxSUWzOO_sMZ4j1lf4drI6NN5bW5SVo-7EWU6IsI3eOs_DxhgRh9osv_VSN8_TmTyP_Em219hpFWkieA5hyTmyc3NPQ3wuHhzGA

You certainly can't parse it as a signed request.

Comment: It’s not a signed request, it’s an access token …

Answer (score 0):

> Auth Token Parameter: If Authenticated Referrals is enabled and when a user authorizes your app through the in-line Auth Dialog, we will pass your app the Auth Token in the format specified here. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals)

Isn’t that pretty clear? You’re getting an OAuth token, with requested permissions already asked for and confirmed by the user – and then you just use that token for your request.

If your choosing client-side auth, you’ll get `#auth_token=…` as hash part of the URL; if you opt for server-side auth, you’ll get it as a query string parameter `?code=…`

Comment: It isn't really clear... to me anyway. I literally do not know what to do with this code variable to get any usable information about the user. I'm really just stumped on it.

Comment: You query the Graph API (or use FQL) if you want information – and you use that access token you just got in your call to prove that you have the right to access the information your asking for … You should really spend some more time on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/